# What's exactly meant here by "on a large scale"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In "The Crime of The Communist" by G. K. Chesterton, Blake was talking about a professor who was suspected to kill two men in the college, saying:

> ‘You mean they found his secret and he silenced them?’ said Blake frowning. ‘But what in hell was his secret? How could a man murder **on a large scale** in a place like this?’

I found that "[on a large scale](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/large-scale)" means "Involving large numbers or a large area; extensive".

But there were just two murdered men, so does it mean here "**more than one person**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*On a large scale* does indeed refer to large numbers. Presumably Mr Blake is deliberately exaggerating, or perhaps he is considering the possibility that the professor might commit more murders.

Comment: Thank you so much, Kate.

Answer (score 1):

When you commit murder over a secret, it is presumably a large secret, one where the consequences of being detected in the murder are less than the consequences of having the secret come out.  Blake is speculating about whether other murders are the secret, but doubting it because it would be difficult.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mary.